# Remove duplicate data from Column A on Excel and Move data From Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have 30000 line of data on excel like on the example below, and i need to remove duplicate data from column A and move data From column B to B C D E F G ..

```
 COLUMN A     COLUMN B
 my data 1     example
 my data 1     other
 my data 1     andother
 my data 2     example
 my data 2     other
 my data 2     andother
 my data 2     otherone
 my data 254     price
 my data 254     change
 my data 254     exact
 my data 254     where
 my data 254     fourniture
 my data 254     exam
 my data 254     yes
```

The result must be like this

```
 COLUMN A     COLUMN B     COLUMN C     COLUMN D     COLUMN E     COLUMN F     COLUMN G     COLUMN H

 my data 1     example     other        andother
 my data 2     example     andother     otherone
 my data 254   price       change       exact        where        fourniture   exam         yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the following data to `Column C`:

`=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)`

And drag down

Secondly copy all values in `Column A` to `H2` (for my example) and click Data>remove duplicate values

Put values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... in cells I1:Z1 or futher if needed

In cell `I2` paste the following array formula:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15,1/(1/SUM(($C$2:$C$15=I$1)*($A$2:$A$15=$H2)*(ROW($C$2:$C$15)-1))),1),"")}`

It's an array formula so leave out the curly braces and enter it by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Drag the formula along and down for required results